# I have an Error 404 on click my account Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm on Prestashop 1.7.5.2 and I can't access to "my account" page...

This is a PHP 7.0 with Apache 2. Mod_rewrite is enable, like URLs friendly.

I have enable debug mode and I have this message : `Notice: Undefined index: controller in Dispatcher.php on line 1049`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Maybe a problem with the language, how many lang are enable on your shop ? did you try without rewriting url ? did you try after disabled non-native modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check in "Traffic & SEO" if "my-account" page has a Friendly URL